# Plot.ly draw reference lines on subplot?

Tags: python, figure, subplot, plotly.js, plotly-python

I wrote the function below to make a vertical reference line on a figure.

```
from plotly import graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px


def add_vline(fig, x=0, text=None):
    if text is None:
        text = str(x)
    fig.update_layout(
        shapes=list(fig.layout.shapes) + [
            go.layout.Shape(
                type="line",
                x0=x,
                x1=x,

                yref="paper",
                y0=0,
                y1=1,

                line=dict(
                    color="Red",
                    width=2
                )
            )
        ],
        annotations=list(fig.layout.annotations) + [
            go.layout.Annotation(
                x=x,
                y=0.5,
                yref="paper",
                text=text
            )
        ]
    )


gapminder = px.data.gapminder()
for continent in gapminder.continent.unique():
    fig = px.histogram(gapminder, x="lifeExp", title=f'Life expectancy in {continent}')
    add_vline(fig, gapminder[gapminder.continent == continent].lifeExp.median())
    # add_figure_to_subplot() ?
```

I can view these individually, but I'd like to make a report with all these generated figures shown in order. How can I either make a subplot of these figure objects, or replicate these plots within subplot traces?

[image]